# Data format on Android Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to send data from an Android app to an Arduino board via Bluetooth.  My test string of bytes is 255, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  However, the string is being received as 255, 1, 2, 32, 80.  This leads me to believe that the data format is different.  I know that the Arduino board is looking for data in an 8 data bit, 1 stop bit, no parity bit format.  By the way the received data is skewed it seems like the Android app is leaving out the stop bit.  Is there a way to set the data format on the Android side?

Comment: I may have solved the problem by slowing down the transfer with a Tread.sleep after each byte is written.

Answer (score 0):

I used a bluetooth modem from sparkfun, and when I used it with the tx/rx pins, it worked find, but if I used SoftSerial and some other pins, it would read garbage when my android app sent too much data.  I also had to unplug the USB from the computer.

To get it working the first time, I spend a bunch of time setting up the modem to match the app I wanted to use, and the blueterm program always seemed to figure out the baud rate and other stop bit / etc fine.